# Is there some way to better explain the operation of *overflow to new users?

Tags: discussion, new-users, help

I have noticed that as more new users are finding and using StackOverflow, there are more questions which do not get flagged as being answered, even though there are sometimes multiple working answers.

New users also seem to be using StackOverflow as a forum, often posting responses, furthering the discussion, or asking another question as an answer, rather than editing their original question.

How should these be handled? Is there a better mechanism to inform new users that this is not a traditional forum? Could StackOverflow perhaps provide more hand holding for the first few questions someone asks?

As mentioned in this [other question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8319/correct-action-for-non-answers-by-new-users), there are certain alternatives; however, I think there could be a preventative answer here.

**Edit:**

Many people below have mentioned videos, tutorials, or even a quiz. These were not the direction I was necessarily thinking.

For example:

When a new user views the answers to his first or second question, perhaps a popup bar, like when receiving a badge, could be displayed mentioning to vote up the answer that best meets their criteria.

Then upon voting up, maybe another notification saying "If this persons's response answers your question, make sure to give them credit by clicking the check mark".

Nothing too intrusive, and it would only happen for the first few questions posed. With a little region highlighting it could probably work well for most people.

Comment: This all falls under the bigger question of "How can StackExchange guide users to being good users?"  A good user is one who marks-up good questions and answers.  Uses comments for comments and answers for answers, marks their questions as answered (when they are), etc...

Comment: Horrible thought: **ClippyOverflow**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just keep pointing them to the FAQ and to meta for questions.

If the site isn't clear and self explanatory, then we have already lost the battle. There is no point to applying band-aids at that point.

We should be looking to *reduce* the barriers to entry on the sites, not *increase* them.

Comment: Requires too much effort. A better solution would be to educate them before they participate IMHO.

Comment: How? A new user test before you are allowed to post? The barrier for entry needs to be as low as possible if you want new users to come at all.

Comment: The system should be (and is IMO) easy enough to use not to need instruction. That is the whole of idea of user interface design.

Comment: I propose -- nay, demand! -- a StackOverflow User's License.

Comment: @Pesto: With videos!

Comment: @EB I'm not suggesting you mandate a video lesson. Only place a couple videos on the "Congrats, you're registered" page in a "Getting Started" area.

Comment: If the user interface were complex or the expected user base were terribly non-technical then I suppose you would have a valid argument. That however is not the case. The UI for S[OUF] is pretty simple. The target audience is the upper end of the technical scale. The sorts of things that a new user needs to know gain nothing by being in a video format.

Comment: @EBGreen: Bravo. Web site design and usability 101.

Comment: @EBGreen while the target audience may be on the upper end of the tech scale, ultimately we will (and do) have people from all levels trying to use it.

Comment: @Darien Ford: Which is why we must keep the barriers down and the usability up.

Comment: Making videos shouldn't be scratched off no matter how easy your UI is. Google makes very simple things, and yet they almost always accommodate their roll outs with a short instructional video. You cannot argue with results - this works. An ounce of evidence out-weighs a pound of theories any day.

Comment: So far, this is the best answer, but I think that (with a little dev help) there could be better ones.  I'll give it another day and then mark this one if nothing else bubbles up.

Answer (score 3):

This issue has existed since the beginning of SO. The users either figure it out or move on generally speaking. The wiki nature of SO means that users that have been around for longer can clean up any mistakes that new users make and set them on the path to being properly overflowish.

Comment: I was tempted to correct you and say "This issue has existed since the beginning of the Internet," but I'm afraid the issue is even older than that.

Answer (score 2):

Activate Francesca's more advanced AI features such that the suggested videos pop up in the middle of the screen whenever someone does something wrong.  These videos cannot be dismissed until they have been completed.

I understand that for some, every click would prompt a video.  I am comfortable with this.

Answer (score 0):

SO needs a couple small videos they show immediately after registering. Small, 30 seconds. One showing how to ask a question (including accepting answers), and another showing how to answer a question (including up-voting/down-voting other answers).

Works for Google.

Comment: A short series on YouTube that we link to in the FAQ might be helpful.  You'd be surprised how many moderator attention flags we get over users just not knowing how to use SO.

Comment: I'm not convinced some people are smart enough to watch the videos.

Comment: Videos are such a truly terrible idea. "You can use our site, just sit here and waste your time watching someone else using our site first." The site should be self explanatory. That is the only answer.

Comment: Goodness, guys. Any video wouldn't be **required**. Sometimes I think people here arbitrarily decide they want to complain about everything. Videos are appealing to many users, especially the large body of "noobish" developers who are coming to SO with simple questions. A short optional video would do wonders for the community. It's a measure to prevent the frustration. Much better than keeping the flood-gates opened and ridiculing new members for abusing the system (out of ignorance of how it works).

Comment: If many people commonly misunderstand you, maybe the problem isn't everyone else.

Comment: Why would you equate "many people" with "everybody else"? If 5 people misunderstand me, maybe the problem is with them.