# Wording of "flag for moderator attention" error should be correct English

Tags: bug, status-completed, spelling

The error message you get if you try to flag more than 10 posts for moderator attention should be differently worded. It should say that you can only flag for moderator attention "10 times per day" instead of just "10 per day":

[image: flag 10 per day]

(It's not that important an issue as the picture makes it look like. Meta just provokes a lot of colors and exclamation marks.)

Comment: +1 for freehand circles, -1 because they aren't red

Comment: No, no, it's bee-utiful

Comment: You do not need a lot of exclamation marks. I hate lot of exclamation marks! I delete lot of exclamation marks (in written next, not in pictures). But +1 for the nice drawing and for improving the site.

Comment: I disagree with Smithers.  Needs more exclamation marks!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: +1 MS Paint (-1 to 15 characters)

Comment: @Mark: "Multiple exclamation marks are a sure sign of a diseased mind." - Terry Pratchett

Comment: @sth - Shouldn't the question be, "Is this comment so bad that I need to involve a moderator's time to review it?"  Did you really see 10 terribly offensive/abusive comments in one day?

Comment: @Adam: There are lots of "answers" given each day that are just noise. Consensus seems to be that those things should be flagged for moderator attention, or at least nobody came up with a better solution yet (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8319/omg-they-dont-know-what-theyre-doing ). And as long as the flagged stuff gets subsequently deleted I think it can't be too wrong to have flagged it... But I already kind of decided to instead just make a big post on meta one day, with a lot of links to stuff that would need to be deleted.

Answer (score 9):

[image]

Comment: I agree that the sentence should be corrected.  We programmers are a picky bunch...

Comment: +1 laughing at first and i misread the badge... then i just laughed harder...